# Java read input with multiple dimension array format

Tags: java, input, format

I wonder how to read "[[1,2,3,4],5]" in console to int A = [1,2,3,4] and int B = 5?
The code below can only read input like"4 1 2 3 4 5" to an array and a constant.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            int N = scanner.nextInt();

            scanner.nextLine();

            int[] A = new int[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                A[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }

            int B = scanner.nextInt();

            int result = Solutions(A, B);

            System.out.println(result);
        }
```

Comment: What's the logic that makes `[[1,2,3,4],5]` result in `A = [1, 2, 3, 4], B = 5`? Last number goes to constant and all others go to the array? Is the input always guaranteed to be in that exact form?

Comment: Yes, so the input is always in the form of '[[A],B]' with the bracket, meaning input an array A and an int number B.

Comment: Then the simplest way is to remove the brackets with `String.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "")`, split it with `String.split(",")` and divide the resulting array as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't think of this way...